# Facebook dialog not rotating when keyboard up

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, rotation

I'm having a problem with FBDialog. 
Apparently after the either the email or the password textFields become first responders and keyboard comes up, the FBDialog view no longer reacts to changing the interface orientation.
Except for the case when keyboard is up, all works as expected. 
Did anyone ever encounter this behavior?

Thanks in advance, Vlad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(void*)object
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = (UIDeviceOrientation)[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if ([self shouldRotateToOrientation:orientation])
    {
        [self updateWebOrientation];
        CGFloat duration = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientationAnimationDuration;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
        [self sizeToFitOrientation:YES];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Comment: already fixed it with a similar approach. This works as well, thanks.

Comment: @Vlad: Can you please explain how you implemented this in your application as I am having similar problem